# Why is LEFT JOIN slower than INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have two queries, the first one (inner join) is super fast, and the second one (left join) is super slow. How do I make the second query fast?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT saved.email FROM saved INNER JOIN finished ON finished.email = saved.email;

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  finished    index   NULL    email   258 NULL    32168   Using index
1   SIMPLE  saved   ref email   email   383 func    1   Using where; Using index

EXPLAIN SELECT saved.email FROM saved LEFT JOIN finished ON finished.email = saved.email;

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  saved   index   NULL    email   383 NULL    40971   Using index
1   SIMPLE  finishedindex   NULL    email   258 NULL    32168   Using index
```

Edit: I have added table info for both tables down below.

```
CREATE TABLE `saved` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  [omitted fields include varchar, text, longtext, int],
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56329 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `finished` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submitted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  [omitted fields include varchar, text, longtext, int],
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `assigned_user_id` (`assigned_user_id`),
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `city_id` (`city_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `recommend` (`recommend`),
  KEY `pending_user_id` (`pending_user_id`),
  KEY `submitted` (`submitted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=33063 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for both tables.

Comment: the output is same for both the queries as you are getting the column from saved table alone, what is the main intention?

Comment: I think this belongs to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How big is `saved` table and what is the number of rows returned by both queries.

Comment: @Marcus Adams: according to the explain output - there is such

Comment: Added SHOW CREATE TABLE output for both tables

Comment: try `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... FROM finished LEFT JOIN saved ...`

Comment: See my updated answer for the actual problem.

Comment: @zerkms, you're assuming things based on the name of an index.

Comment: @Marcus Adams: uhm, not sure what you mean. 1. There are schemas available already 2. In the given query only `email` column is used for predicates and `SELECT` which automatically means that if any index is used - then `email` is its left most part. So, excuse me, but my "assumption" is based on facts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With INNER JOIN, MySQL generally will start with the table with the smallest number of rows. In this case, it starts with table `finished` and does a look up for the corresponding record in `saved` using the index on `saved.email`.

For a LEFT JOIN, (excluding some optimizations) MySQL generally joins the records in order (starting with the left most table). In this case, MySQL starts with the table `saved`, then attempts to find each corresponding record in `finished`. Since there is no **usable** index on `finished.email`, it must do a full scan for each look up.

**Edit**

Now that you posted your schema, I can see that MySQL is ignoring the index (`finished.email`) when going from `utf8` to `latin1` character set. You've not posted the character sets and collations for each column, so I'm going by the default character set for the table. The collations must be compatible in order for MySQL to use the index.

MySQL can coerce (upgrade) a `latin1` collation, which is very limited, up to a `utf8` collation such as `unicode_ci` (so the first query can use the index on `saved.email` by upgrading `latin1` collation to `utf8`), but the opposite is not true (the second query can't use the index on `finished.email` since it can't downgrade a `utf8` collation down to `latin1`).

The solution is to change both email columns to a compatible collation, perhaps most easily by making them identical character sets and collations.

Comment: But there is an index on finished.email.

Comment: Good catch on the difference in the characterset.

Comment: Character set point was a really great one. Made a query of mine go down from 1 hour to 87ms

Comment: "The collations must be compatible in order for MySQL to use the index." -- Thanks, I hadn't considered looking at the collation as part of my problem. I converted the tables to use the same collation, and it took my multiple-minute query down to a second or so. Thanks!

Comment: oh my god, you are life saver!
Our query went from 8h to 1 minute because we were using different enccoding formats in our tables.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

The `LEFT JOIN` query is *slower* than the `INNER JOIN` query because it's *doing more work*.

From the EXPLAIN output, it looks like MySQL is doing nested loop join. (There's nothing wrong with nested loops; I think that's the only join operation that MySQL uses in version 5.5 and earlier.)

For the `INNER JOIN` query, MySQL is using an efficient **`"ref"`** (index lookup) operation to locate the matching rows.

But for the `LEFT JOIN` query, it looks like MySQL is doing a **full scan** of the index to find the matching rows.  So, with the nested loops join operation, MySQL is doing a full index scan scan for **each row** from the other table. So, that's on the order of tens of thousands of scans, and each of those scans is inspecting tens of thousands of rows.

Using the estimated row counts from the EXPLAIN output, that's going to require (40971*32168=)  1,317,955,128 string comparisons.

The `INNER JOIN` query avoids a lot of that work, so it's a lot *faster*. (It's avoiding all those string comparisons by using an index operation.

```
-- LEFT JOIN
id select table    type   key   key_len ref    rows  Extra
-- ------ -------- -----  ----- ------- ----  -----  ------------------------
1  SIMPLE saved    index  email     383 NULL  40971  Using index
1  SIMPLE finished index  email     258 NULL  32168  Using index

-- INNER JOIN 
id select table    type   key   key_len ref    rows  Extra
-- ------ -------- -----  ----- ------- ----  -----  ------------------------  
1  SIMPLE finished index  email     258 NULL  32168  Using index
1  SIMPLE saved    ref    email     383 func      1  Using where; Using index
                   ^^^^^                ^^^^  ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

**NOTE:** Markus Adams spied the difference in characterset in the `email` columns **`CREATE TABLE`** statements that were added to your question.

I believe that it's the difference in the characterset that's preventing MySQL from using an index for your query.

---

**Q2: How do I make the LEFT JOIN query faster?**

**A:** I don't believe it's going to be possible to get that specific query to run faster, without a schema change, such as changing the characterset of the two email columns to match.

The only affect that the "outer join" to the `finished` table looks like it is to produce "duplicate" rows whenever more than one matching row is found.  I'm not understanding why the outer join is needed. Why not just get rid of it altogether, and just do:

```
SELECT saved.email FROM saved
```

Comment: Aaaaand we have the winner :-) Nice explanation, +1

Comment: I missed the difference in characterset (Markus spied it) that may probably explain why MySQL isn't using a "ref" join operation.

Comment: I'm going to accept Adam's answer because the character set is the culprit but thank you for the detailed explanation of how LEFT JOINs differ from INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid more info will probably be needed.

However, `inner joins` eliminate any item that has a null foreign key (no match, if you will). This means that there are less rows to scan to associate.

For a `left join` however, any non-match needs to be given a blank row, so all of the rows are scanned regardless -- nothing can be eliminated.

This makes the data set larger and requires more resources to process. Also, when you write your select, don't do `select *` -- instead, explicitly state which columns you want.

Comment: There are no row scans happening here at all.  You are correct that more rows are returned in the LEFT JOIN, but the join is able to be calculated using index in either case as shown in the explain.

Comment: @MikeBrant, `Using index` doesn't mean it used the index to satisfy the `WHERE`. `Using where; Using index` means it used the index to satisfy the `WHERE`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams There is no WHERE clause in the example. I was talking about the indexes being used to satisfy the join condition.

Comment: @Mike Brant: actually that's not true. `using index` without `using where` means the index was read just to fetch the data (to avoid reading the actual data pages). So in the second `EXPLAIN` output it's basically an index full scan, not lookup. Hence it's slow. And there is `WHERE` in the first query (the `ON` node transformed into `WHERE` clause during optimization)

Comment: @zerks Yes agreed that the indexes are scanned and read into memory.  I was more making note that the answer refers to all rows being scanned. Seemed to be hinting at full table scan, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Mike Brant: it is still a full index scan, which causes exactly the same effect: cartesian product of 2 sets. So from my point it's fair to say so (but it needs to be carefully explained indeed to avoid further confusion). However I completely agree the explanation of the roots of the issue is kind of vague and in the current form it does not explain anything :-)

Answer (score 1):

The data types of `saved.email` and `finished.email` differ in two respects.  First, they have different lengths. Second, `finished.email` can be NULL. So, your `LEFT JOIN` operation can't exploit the index on `finished.email`.

Can you change the definition of `finished.email` to this, so it matches the field you're joining it with?

```
`email` varchar(127) NOT NULL
```

If you do you'll probably get a speedup.