# Laravel/MySQL: Very high query runtime

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

In my laravel project I am currently doing some testing with database seeders to check the performance with many database entries. In my project I have a Model FlightView using a SQL view as database by doing `protected $table = 'view_flights';`.

During testing I realized that queries like `FlightView::where('aircraft_id',1)->get()` are getting very slow (2 or 2.5 seconds per call). I am evaluation the query runtime in laravel with [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

I realized, that the underlying query is handled differently when filtering on one aircraft id (runtime 2 to 2.5 seconds), but is very fast when filtering on two or more aircraft id (runtime around 100 ms). By checking the underling view query I did some optimizations by replacing a LEFT JOIN into a INNER JOIN, so that in both cases a "ref" (index lookup) is being used ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787269/why-is-left-join-slower-than-inner-join)).

After updating the view, the runtime within my SQL editor became 50 to 100 ms. However, within laravel with exactly the same queries are still enormously long:

```
FlightView::where('aircraft_id',1)->get()
Runtime: 2.23 sec
Query: select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` = 1
```

I tried lots of variations as you can see in the following results, but I didn't get a clue what is going wrong or what I could do next...

```
FlightView::whereIn('aircraft_id',[1])->get()
Runtime: 2.24 sec
Query: select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` in (1)
```

To exclude any Eloquent issues, I tried the same with the DB Facade, but it's still slow.

```
DB::table('view_flights')->where('aircraft_id',1)->get()
Runtime: 2.22 sec
Query: select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` = 1
```

Next I tried to `DB::select()` statement, but also no improvement:

```
DB::select('select * from view_flights where aircraft_id=?',[1]);
Runtime: 2.22 sec
Query: select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` = 1
```

Without bindings, the query speed increased a lot:
Next I tried to `DB::select()` statement, but also no improvement:

```
DB::select('select * from view_flights where aircraft_id=1');
Runtime: 23 ms
Query: select * from view_flights where aircraft_id = 1
```

Surprisingly, when filtering on two aircraft ids, the laravel query is still very fast:

```
FlightView::whereIn('aircraft_id',[1,2])->get()
Runtime: 53 ms
Query: select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` in (1,2)
```

Next, I let laravel try to explain, why it is so slow:

```
DB::select('explain select * from view_flights where aircraft_id=?',[1]);
Runtime: 2.22 sec
Query: explain select * from `view_flights` where `aircraft_id` = 1
```

[image]

So Laravel seems still to do the "slow" query approach, not the "ref" (index lookup) approach :-(

Speculations/open questions?

- Is the problem a laravel specific or a SQL-specific problem?
- Are there any MySQL settings, which may lead to the different behaviour?
- What could be the reason, that laravel handles a query different than my sql editor?
- Is there same kind of "SQL view"-caching or in Laravel, which might still use the old version of the view?
- Is there any "magic" within laravel which might explain this behaviour?
- What could I do next?

Comment: Do you have an index on aircraft_id? Or can you tell us how many records are in the view_flights table?

Comment: Can you compare the explain with the query that is faster?

Comment: @George G: The view contains approximately 110.000 records. There is an index on aircraft_id in the underlying base table of view_flight.

Comment: @apokryfos From my query optimization I know, that the slower queries contain the "derived all" with 120000 rows, whereas the fast shows "derived ref" with only 16 rows. All queries executed in  my sql editor now only contain "derived ref"s, but the laravel query is still a "derived all". Unfortuneately, I do not understand, how the identical queries is handled in different ways between my sql editor and laravel.

Comment: @ThomasSpäth something that comes to my mind (that could or could not be related it) is do you have, on the MySQL config file (`config/database.php`), `strict => true`? What config do you have in there for this connection?

Comment: @matiaslauriti: Yes, ```strict => true```. However, changing it to ```strict => false``` and running ```php artisan config:clear``` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I think you should run a command where you can get all the local/global environment variables set for MySQL (internals to MySQL) and do the same on the other terminal where it runs faster. I am thinking that there is something set on either that makes the MySQL engine choose a path of resolution based on those environment variables. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html. I would run `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` on both the fast terminal and Laravel connection, so you can compare what is different, and show it to us

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE view_flights`. And, after a big bulk-load operation don't forget to say `OPTIMIZE TABLE view_flights` to reorganize indexes and recompute quey-planner statistics.

Comment: You can use the `explain()` method on the query builder to see if it's any different. `$explain = FlightView::whereIn('aircraft_id', [1])->explain();`

Comment: Does running the query in the editor using a prepared statement and parameters behave the same as in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some suggestions.

I hope it helps you to fix the optimization problem.

- As they said in the comments make sure you have an index on the "aircraft_id" column.
- Select only the necessary columns.
- Tuning Mysql performance:
  Sometimes the problem is on the database side, and performance can be increased with performance tuning. Especially since 110,000 records is not a big number.

Answer (score 0):

What the datatype of `aircraft_id`?  If it is `VARCHAR`, then the problem is in testing against a number.  Change `1` to `"1"`.  As you have it, it will convert each row's aircraft_id to a string before testing.

(That advice applies to your `IN`, etc, too.)

And, do have `INDEX(aircraft_id)`.